# Map response from HttpClient to Array of Objects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

Using Angular 7 I had this:

```
export class Envelope<T> {
  result: T[];

  constructor(result: T[]) {
    this.result = result;
  }
}
```

I mapped `Observable<Envelope<Todo>>`, return by todoService, to `Observable<TodoModel[]>`:

```
let models: Observable<TodoModel[]> = this.todoService.get()
  .pipe(
    map((envelope: Envelope<Todo>) => 
      envelope.result.map((todo: Todo) => { 
        return {
          content: todo.content
          // Other properties
        };
      })));
```

This is working but now Envelope changed to (`result: T` and not `result: T[]`):

```
export class Envelope<T> {
  result: T;

  constructor(result: T) {
    this.result = result;
  }
}
```

I need to map `Observable<Envelope<Todo[]>>` to the same `Observable<TodoModel[]>`:

```
let models: Observable<TodoModel[]> = this.todoService.get()
  .pipe(
    map((envelope: Envelope<Todo[]>) => 
      envelope.result.map((todo: Todo) => { 
        return {
          content: todo.content
          // Other properties
        };
      })));
```

I tried a few options but I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Envelope<Todo[]>, { content: string; }[]>' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Envelope<Todo>, { content: string; }[]>'.

Type 'Envelope<Todo[]>' is not assignable to type 'Envelope<Todo>'.
Type 'Todo[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': content.
```

Could someone, please, let me know how to do the mapping?

**Update**

The API returns, for example, something as follows:

```
{
  "result": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "T1", content: "C1" },
    { "id": 2, "title": "T2", content: "C2" }
  ]
}
```

Then the TodoService returns it as an `Observable<Envelope<Todo[]>>` where `Todo` is:

```
interface Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
}
```

In the component I need to map `Observable<Envelope<Todo[]>>` to `Observable<TodoModel[]>` where `TodoModel` is:

```
interface TodoModel {
  title: string;
  content: string;
}
```

I have more complex scenarios in my application but the base is this.

Comment: `envelope.result.map` maps an Object and returns a mapped Object. It will never return Array. And if you change type from `envelope: Envelope<Todo>` to `envelope: Envelope<Todo[]>`, it will not impact output in any way. It is not a run time code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your answer ... Could you, please, post a code sample?

Comment: It would be best if you show what data you get and what data shape you want it to turn in

Comment: I added an update ... Does it help?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to observe the envelope?  Maybe something like this would more straight forward. If the envelope contains a list of todos

```
result: Observable<TodoModel>; 

    this.todoService.get()
          .subscribe((envelope: any) => {
            this.result = envelope.todo.content;       
          });
```

Comment: Envelope has other information like Paging which is related with result itself ... Shouldn't I include it?